# Building docs for playframework

Tags: build, playframework, sbt

was trying to fix a simple issue on playframework's github page but in order to do so I have to build docs.

Accordingly to their [readme](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/documentation/README.md) i have to use 
`sbt run` to do so, but at the end (after about 20 or so minutes) i get an error:

```
[info] Packaging /home/ubuntu/playframework/framework/src/play-docs/target/scala-2.12/play-docs_2.12-2.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-docs_2.12;2.7.0-SNAPSHOT: not found
    at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:320)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:191)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:168)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:156)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:156)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:133)
    at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:57)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$4.call(Ivy.scala:65)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:95)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:80)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:99)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:60)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:50)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:65)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:128)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:125)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:156)
    at sbt.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:168)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1555)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1551)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$122.apply(Defaults.scala:1586)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$122.apply(Defaults.scala:1584)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:37)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1589)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1583)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:60)
    at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1606)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1533)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1485)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] (Play-Documentation/*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-docs_2.12;2.7.0-SNAPSHOT: not found
[error] Total time: 334 s, completed Nov 1, 2018 9:13:23 PM
```

So i begun to investigate. I setup a fresh copy of Ubuntu Desktop 18.4, installed java 8, Sbt, increased heap size to 2 GB and tried again. Unfortunately with the same result.

For the sake of completeness here is my java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_191"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)
```

also first few lines after `sbt run` suggests scala version imported by sbt:

```
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.17  (this may take some time)...
```

Does anyone know if it is an issue with my configuration (or configurations because i have tested that on Windows 10 PC, Fedora 28 and fresh Ubuntu 18.4) or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I have found an answer. It wasn't clear that i need to run `sbt publishLocal` before `sbt run`. Sometimes i have some other errors that are like "X was not found", then simply build package with:

```
cd $PLAY_HOME/framework
sbt compile doc package
```

Have fun!